# How to add values to priority queue(reverse order) used as a value in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, priority-queue

How to add values to priority queue(reverse order) used as a value in HashMap

I know how to declare a priority in a reverse order using, like below

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

I know how to declare priority queue as a value in a hashmap, like below

```
Map<Integer,PriorityQueue<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

I would like to know, can I declare priority queue in reverseOrder as a value in hashmap in java?

Comment: The ordering of value(PriorityQueue<Integer>) in the map depends on how you call `put` in the map. Just call `put(key,new PriorityQueue<Integer>(Collections.reverseOrder()))` if you need the value in reverse order.

Comment: Just to add some information to the @samabcde answer:
A "Reversed" PriorityQueue is always a PriorityQueue but with a different Comparator (provided by Collections.reverseOrder()).

Comment: @samabcde Thanks for the clarification, how did I miss that, I am so dumb :(